# Falta uma tradução na fila de análise

Tags: bug, tradução

Na [página da fila de análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review) falta uma tradução.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sugiro a seguinte tradução:

> **Stack Overflow em Português é moderado por você.**
>
> Ajude a melhorá-lo avaliando novas publicações, votando para fechar or reabrir perguntas, ou revisando edições sugeridas.

Comment: Acho que está parte não está disponível para tradução pelo pt.traducir.win, então parece que teremos que enviar diretamente ao pessoal da SE.

Comment: Está aqui: https://pt.traducir.win/string/9861 @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Opa, melhor ainda... para mim não haveria aparecido. Já aprovei a sugestão, só esperar o review